# Calculate rolling time difference in pandas efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panel in pandas and am trying to calculate the amount of time that an individual spends in each stage. To give a better sense of this my dataset is as follows:

```
group       date    stage  
 A     2014-01-01   one   
 A     2014-01-03   one    
 A     2014-01-04   one    
 A     2014-01-05   two    
 B     2014-01-02  four    
 B     2014-01-06  five    
 B     2014-01-10  five    
 C     2014-01-03   two    
 C     2014-01-05   two
```

I'm looking to calculate stage duration to give:

```
 group       date    stage  dur
  A     2014-01-01   one    0
  A     2014-01-03   one    2
  A     2014-01-04   one    3
  A     2014-01-05   two    0
  B     2014-01-02  four    0
  B     2014-01-06  five    0
  B     2014-01-10  five    4
  C     2014-01-03   two    0
  C     2014-01-05   two    2
```

The method that I'm using below is extremely slow. Any ideas on a quicker method?

```
df['stage_duration'] = df.groupby(['group', 'stage']).date.apply(lambda y: (y - y.iloc[0])).apply(lambda y:y / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')))
```

Comment: You don't need the final apply, see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions, you can simply ``astype('timedelta64[D]')`` or divide by ``np.timedelta64(1,'D')`` (they are sligthly different in how they round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based your code (your `groupby/apply`), it looks like (despite your example ... but maybe I misunderstand what you want and then what Andy did would be the best idea) that you're working with a 'date' column that is a `datetime64` dtype and not an `integer` dtype in your actual data. Also it looks like you want compute the change in days as measured from the first observation of a given `group/stage`. I think this is a better set of example data (if I understand your goal correctly):

```
>>> df

  group       date stage  dur
0     A 2014-01-01   one    0
1     A 2014-01-03   one    2
2     A 2014-01-04   one    3
3     A 2014-01-05   two    0
4     B 2014-01-02  four    0
5     B 2014-01-06  five    0
6     B 2014-01-10  five    4
7     C 2014-01-03   two    0
8     C 2014-01-05   two    2
```

Given that you should get some speed-up from just modifying your apply (as Jeff suggests in his comment) by dividing through by the `timedelta64` in a vectorized way after the apply (or you could do it in the apply):

```
>>> df['dur'] = df.groupby(['group','stage']).date.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])
>>> df['dur'] /= np.timedelta64(1,'D')
>>> df

  group       date stage  dur
0     A 2014-01-01   one    0
1     A 2014-01-03   one    2
2     A 2014-01-04   one    3
3     A 2014-01-05   two    0
4     B 2014-01-02  four    0
5     B 2014-01-06  five    0
6     B 2014-01-10  five    4
7     C 2014-01-03   two    0
8     C 2014-01-05   two    2
```

But you can also avoid the `groupby/apply` given your data is in group,stage,date order. The first date for every `['group','stage']` grouping happens when either the group changes or the stage changes. So I think you can do something like the following:

```
>>> beg = (df.group != df.group.shift(1)) | (df.stage != df.stage.shift(1))
>>> df['dur'] = (df['date'] - df['date'].where(beg).ffill())/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
>>> df

  group       date stage  dur
0     A 2014-01-01   one    0
1     A 2014-01-03   one    2
2     A 2014-01-04   one    3
3     A 2014-01-05   two    0
4     B 2014-01-02  four    0
5     B 2014-01-06  five    0
6     B 2014-01-10  five    4
7     C 2014-01-03   two    0
8     C 2014-01-05   two    2
```

Explanation: Note what `df['date'].where(beg)` creates:

```
>>> beg = (df.group != df.group.shift(1)) | (df.stage != df.stage.shift(1))
>>> df['date'].where(beg)

0   2014-01-01
1          NaT
2          NaT
3   2014-01-05
4   2014-01-02
5   2014-01-06
6          NaT
7   2014-01-03
8          NaT
```

And then I `ffill` the values and take the difference with the 'date' column.

**Edit:** As Andy points out you could also use `transform`:

```
>>> df['dur'] = df.date - df.groupby(['group','stage']).date.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
>>> df['dur'] /= np.timedelta64(1,'D')

  group       date stage  dur
0     A 2014-01-01   one    0
1     A 2014-01-03   one    2
2     A 2014-01-04   one    3
3     A 2014-01-05   two    0
4     B 2014-01-02  four    0
5     B 2014-01-06  five    0
6     B 2014-01-10  five    4
7     C 2014-01-03   two    0
8     C 2014-01-05   two    2
```

**Speed**: I timed the two method using a similar dataframe with 400,000 observations:

Apply method:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 18.3 s per loop
```

Non-apply method:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 1.64 s per loop
```

So I think avoiding the apply could give some significant speed-ups

Comment: +1 This probably makes more sense for what OP wants... I think you may be able to do this more efficiently using a transform.

Comment: Yeah @Andy, I thought about `transform` but at least for 0.13.1 I usually find transform no faster than a generic `apply` so I didn't include it. But I will update the answer with that as an alternative.

Comment: Interested to see if it's faster, my guess is that it would be (though will be dependant on group sizes - suspect will be faster if larger groups).

Comment: @Andy, I'm getting `transform` as much slower. I thought Jeff had mentioned some performance issues with `transform` but maybe I am misremembering.

Comment: oop, yep your method is much faster (as specialized to this contiguous case), had misread your second solution!

Comment: So much better. I tested it and it is as your profiling suggested nearly 20x better

Answer (score 5):

I think I'd use `diff` here:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('stage')['date'].diff().fillna(0)
Out[11]:
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    4
dtype: float64
```

(Assuming that the stages are contiguous.)

If you are just subtracting the first in each group, use a [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
In [21]: df['date'] - df.groupby('stage')['date'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[21]:
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    4
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Note: this is probably significantly faster...