# Calculate time difference between two datetimes within group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that shows me everyday call records and what happened to that call. I need to group the call records by caller ID, date, and description of the call, count the number of times that caller called in a day, and the time difference between them.

My current dataset is

```
Call record ID | DiscriptionCallEvent | CallDateTime |

14306187       |  CallTerminated      | 2021-02-08 17:48:04
14306189       |  AbandonedQueue      | 2021-02-08 18:18:44 
14306189       |  AbandonedQueue      | 2021-02-08 18:19:20
14306189       |  AbandonedQueue      | 2021-02-08 18:20:00
14306189       |  Caller termintaed   | 2021-02-08 19:20:00
```

The second caller here called 2 times back to back. What I am trying to do is capture the information in this way.

```
Call record ID | DiscriptionCallEvent | CallDate | #Times | TimeDiff
 14306189         AbandonedQueue       2021-02-08    3        2 minutes (say)
 14306189         Caller terminated    2021-02-08    1        1 hour
```

I was able to group by record ID and description and date and count the number of times the call occurred. But I am not able to find the time difference within the group. I tried many StackOverflow solution but did not work.

Currently, I am using this query:

```
CallsGrouped=df.groupby(["CallRecordID","CallDate","DiscriptionCallEvent "],as_index=False)['Call Record ID'].count()
```

How do I modify the query such that I can find the time difference as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate rolling time difference in pandas efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796191/calculate-rolling-time-difference-in-pandas-efficiently)